# Get string between two specific characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table fileslist with column Filetext which contains text data

```
create table fileslist  
(  
FileID int identity (1,1),  
Filetext nvarchar(max)  
) 

insert into fileslist select 'this file(''SQL_SCALAR1'') has been created to test your tricks of (''SQL_SCALAR2'')'   
insert into fileslist select 'this file(''SCALAR3'') created to test your tricks of (''SQL_SCALAR4'')'  
insert into fileslist select 'this file(''SQL_SCALAR5'') has been created to test your tricks of (''SQL_SCALAR6'')'   
insert into fileslist select 'this file(''SQL_7'') has been created'     
insert into fileslist select 'this file(''SQL_SCALAR8'') has been created to test your tricks of (''SQL_SCALAR9''), ohh i have more text than other (''SQL_SCALAR10'')files'
```

I need help to read all records one by one to extract string between two specific characters '(' and ')' and Output should be

```
SQL_SCALAR1  
SQL_SCALAR2   
SCALAR3  
SQL_SCALAR4  
SQL_SCALAR5  
SQL_SCALAR6  
SQL_7  
SQL_SCALAR8  
SQL_SCALAR9  
SQL_SCALAR10
```

Comment: Have update my answer - sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Here is a nice example [How to parse a string with complex CHARINDEX?](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/complexcharindex/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I would choose this approach is that it handles a dynamic number of the patterns you are searching for, per row, very well.

First I would use Jeff Moden's string splitter;

```
/*
 * Jeff Moden's famous string spliiter
 * http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
 */

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

Then, I would write the following;

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING   (
                        Item, 
                        2, 
                        CHARINDEX(')', Item) - 3
                    )
FROM FilesList
CROSS 
APPLY [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](FileText, '(')
WHERE Item LIKE '''SQL%'
```

**As requested in comment; (I'm not thrilled about butchering Jeff's code this way...)**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K_Butchered]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @DelimiterA CHAR(1), @DelimiterB CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @DelimiterA
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@DelimiterA,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                ),
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
OriginalOutput AS
(
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
)
    SELECT 
        Item    = SUBSTRING (
                                Item, 
                                1, 
                                CHARINDEX(@DelimiterB, Item) - 1
                            )
    FROM OriginalOutput 
    WHERE Item LIKE '%' + @DelimiterB + '%'
    --AND SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1) LIKE '%' + @DelimiterB + '%'
;
GO
```

Used as follows;

```
SELECT  *
FROM FilesList
CROSS 
APPLY [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K_Butchered](FileText, '(', ')')
```

Comment: using this query we can't get SQL_SCALAR2, SQL_SCALAR4,SQL_SCALAR6

Comment: Ah... I'm sorry - I will adjust

Comment: Mark is this possible we can create a table valued function that take input '(' and ')' and return all strings between these characters which may not be LIKE '''SQL%' or Fixed number of characters, i have made changes in my question

Comment: Yes - will place in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @ss varchar(100)= 'this file(''SQL_SCALAR1'') has been created to test your tricks of (''SQL_SCALAR2'')'
```

Not sure how you want to display

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING ( (LEFT(@ss,CHARINDEX(')',@ss) - 1)),CHARINDEX('(',@ss)+1,LEN(LEFT(@ss,CHARINDEX(')',@ss) - 1))),
        SUBSTRING ((RIGHT(@ss,CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(@ss)) - 1)),1,LEN(RIGHT(@ss,CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(@ss)) - 1))-1)
```

OR

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING ( (LEFT(@ss,CHARINDEX(')',@ss) - 1)),CHARINDEX('(',@ss)+1,LEN(LEFT(@ss,CHARINDEX(')',@ss) - 1)))
Union
SELECT  SUBSTRING ((RIGHT(@ss,CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(@ss)) - 1)),1,LEN(RIGHT(@ss,CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(@ss)) - 1))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution what you are looking for, cheer....

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT SUBSTRING(FILETEXT,CHARINDEX('(',FileText,1)+2,11) 'Result'  
FROM FILESLIST
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(
    (SUBSTRING(FILETEXT,CHARINDEX(')',FILETEXT,1)+1,LEN(FILETEXT)-               
    CHARINDEX(')',FILETEXT,1))  ) 
    ,CHARINDEX('(',(SUBSTRING(FILETEXT,CHARINDEX(')',FILETEXT,1)+1,LEN(FILETEXT)-
    CHARINDEX(')',FILETEXT,1))  ) ,1)+2,11
) 'Result'
FROM FILESLIST
) T1
WHERE Result like '%SQL%'
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY RESULT ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with recursive `CTE` is

```
WITH REP AS (
  SELECT FileID
       , Filetext = REPLACE(Filetext, ')', '(')
  FROM   fileslist
), Splitter AS (
  SELECT FileID
       , FileText
       , NextStart = CHARINDEX('(', FileText)
       , Pos = 0
       , Token = CAST(SubString(FileText, 0, CHARINDEX('(', FileText)) 
                      AS NVarchar(50))
  FROM   REP
  UNION ALL
  SELECT FileId
       , FileText
       , NextStart = CHARINDEX('(', FileText, NextStart + 1)
       , Pos = Pos + 1
       , Token = CAST(SubString(FileText, NextStart + 1
                              , CHARINDEX('(', FileText, NextStart + 1) 
                              - NextStart - 1) AS NVarchar(50))
  FROM   Splitter
  WHERE  CHARINDEX('(', FileText, NextStart + 1) - NextStart - 1 > 0
)
SELECT FileID, Token
FROM   REC
WHERE  Pos % 2 = 1
order by FileID, Pos
```

The `Splitter` `CTE` split the rows using a single delimiter, so before use it we need to make the two delimiter the same. Only the odd token are returned by the main query because the even token are other part of the string, for example the string `'this file(''SQL_7'') has been created'` will be returned by the `Splitter` like (with only the interesting columns):

```
Pos | Token
----+------------------
  0 | this file
  1 | SQL_7
  2 | has been created
```